# How can I use JSHint offline on Windows?

Tags: javascript, windows, jshint

JSHint is built into PHPStorm, but I'm  looking for a standalone version.

Comment: There are some nice links at the top of the homepage: http://www.jshint.com/platforms/

Comment: Why all the negativity here? As in really? why is this being -1'd? also cheers quentin i'll have a look.

Comment: @JamieHutber: your [writing style](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/11449148/2) didn't really encourage a positive reaction. I've edited the question so it might get reopened one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phpstorm has a built in version of JSHint:

```
Settings ¬ Javascript ¬ Code Quality Tools ¬ JSHINT ¬ Enable
```